# pandas groupby object to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {"name" : ["name1", "name1", "name2", "name3", "name3" , "name3"], "item" : ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item2", "item3", "item1"] } )
df2 = df1.groupby('name')['item']
```

In this groupby object I have all the items for each name. I can visualise this through:

```
print(df2.apply(list))
```

and get:

```
name
name1           [item1, item2]
name2                  [item3]
name3    [item2, item3, item1]
```

what I, however, would like to achieve is something like this:

```
name     itemA    itemB    itemC
name1    item1    item2    NaN
name2    item3    NaN      NaN
name3    item2    item3    item1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `apply` `pd.Series` at the end of your df2

```
df2.apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
Out[300]: 
           0      1      2
name                      
name1  item1  item2    NaN
name2  item3    NaN    NaN
name3  item2  item3  item1
```

Comment: Excellent. That's perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Christian yw :-)

Comment: To me it seems like the object is not as asked for. The example has a flat header structure, while the answers result has the multi index structure. Can one flatten it out well?

Answer (score -1):

Added column name in [Wen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48750322/1924666)

```
>>> df3 = df2.apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
>>> df3.columns = ['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC']
# df3 = df3.rename(columns={0: 'itemA', 1: 'itemB', 2: 'itemC'})
>>> df3
       itemA  itemB  itemC
name                      
name1  item1  item2    NaN
name2  item3    NaN    NaN
name3  item2  item3  item1
```